# Block request without Authorization Token

Tags: java, retrofit2, okhttp, bearer-token

I'm working on Android App using Retrofit and OkHttp library to implements REST client. My app consumes secured REST web services. My code to initialize the Retrofit client is:

```java
...
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .callTimeout(240, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(240, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .addInterceptor(chain -> {
           Request.Builder ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder();
           ongoing.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

           if (token != null) {
              ongoing.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer: " + token);
           } else {
             //TODO block the call
           }

           return chain.proceed(ongoing.build());
   }).addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
...
```

In case `token` is `null` I need to block the request call and return directly a `401 response`. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you do a call without a token anyway?

Comment: I invoke the REST service without checking if I have the token because I put it directly in the interceptor.